# How to handle status ids in database

Tags: sql, database, data-structures

Assume that I have tables in db `'Product'` and `'Status'`.

```
'Product' design is: Id, Name StatusId

'Status' design is: Id, Name
```

**'Status' data is(for example): 1-Reserve, 2-Paid**

**Question is:** When i want to reserve some product from UI, how to get right Id from Status table? How to handle them?

I have some solutions for it: just hold in mind, that 1 is Reserve, 2 is Paid. Another one is to use 'Key', but problem is: may be in future you will add another status, for example 3-Returned.

**EDITED:**

Thanks for answers, but question is about another problem.
This problem comes when you want to `Create new UI for reservation only`, for example you provide inputs for user data(Username, contacts) and Choose product options and click button 'Reserve', After that I need to save all data in Database, but i need StatusId as reservtion from Status table. `How I know which record in 'Status' table is Reservation?`

Answer (score 0):

Populate a list of `Status` objects from the DB every time you prepare your view (UI) data. So that you can show it in the view as some select combo. In case you add new row to `statuses` table, next time your list will have them.
In case you don't update your statuses often, you can load this list only on app start/ once per session.

EDIT:
Usually in any combo widget you can define the list of options as pairs (id,name). In your case it would be [(1, Reserved), (2, Paid)] so that selected value of combobox is an id. That id is what you save in the DB.

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, but I expanded the answer.

Comment: I am not going to use combo, i just want to create UI for reservation, when user provide all inputs, he just clicks 'Reserve' button, and then he pays money through terminal and my program must update product as 'Paid'.

Comment: If it's not just a list, but every entry has a reference in the code, then you probably will better off with `enum` and not a table. The new 'Returned' status will require redeployment, but if you add new status along with new functionality you'll have to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my idea...You can have FK from 'Status' to 'Product' like below :

> 'Product' design is: Id, Name , FK_IdStatus StatusId
>   'Status' design is: Id, Name

then in UI You select all 'Status' into a combobox to select

> Select Id,Name From Status  ... and assign this datatable to combobox datasource and choose combobox.ValueMember= "Id" and combobox.DisplayMember="Name"

then you can select any Status for your Products in UI by select a status from combobox
and in your 'Product' table is stored a FK_IdStatus for every Product

Answer (score 0):

vadchen is right too... I can tell you to have **enum**  instead of having table 'Status' and you can save the enum's Id of 'Status' in your 'Product' table

if you are not going to have combo and then you are managing your types during every process.
I meant this...

> Process A causes to 1.Reserved 
>   Process B causes to 2.Paid
>   Process C causes to 3.another Status
>   and so on...

Then in this case, you know that **the process A always causes to 1.Reserved** then if you have any other process (like Process C ) you have to manage it to other 'Status'

But in my idea you have to keep this enum type number (Status Id) in your 'Product' table as an **"int"** not as a nvarchar type... like below:

> 'Product' design is: Id, Name , IdStatusType (as int)

then you can remove 'Status' tables and you know the Id's StatusType in your 'Product' table